# Are .bz2 files inside /var/lib/pengine safe to delete?

Tags: disk-usage, directory-structure

My problem is that my `/var` partition is over 80% (total size: 4.9G). I was reviewing the files into this partition and I saw a file which has 3.4G. (`/var/lib/pengine`)

I dig into that /pengine file and I saw it is full of `.bz2` extension files. I want to move these files but I would like to know if is risky or not.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand your problem. Could you make it more clear?

Comment: I edited the main message :)

Comment: How about file names?

Comment: [There's a mailing list thread on the issue of Pacemaker filling up `/var/lib/pengine`](http://oss.clusterlabs.org/pipermail/pacemaker/2010-May/006256.html), maybe it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bz2 is a type of data compression, it soesn;t tell anything about the purpose of the files .

Pengine (whatever that is, a game?) probably needs them.

If the files are using up most of the space on var you could consider
moving them to a partition with more space eg /home

```
# umask 22
# mkdir /home/var_lib_overflow
# mv /var/lib/pengine /home/var_lib_overflow/
# ln -s /home/var_lib_overflow/pengine /var/lib/
```

FHS  suggests they could be "crash recovery files" from an editor 
in whih case they should go away by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Yes, the files are safe to delete - they are basically just backups of previous cluster states. But...

**Long answer**: The Policy Engine (the part of a Pacemaker cluster which decides what to do when something happens within the cluster) safes backups of the cluster state (configuration and state of resources) to `/var/lib/pengine`. These files are not vital (or actually even used) for the operation of the cluster, but might come in handy when investigating failures, because the logs are usually pretty sparse about these things.

So it's wise to keep a few of those around, but on a busy cluster they can clog up the partition after a while. You can limit the number of files kept by pengine by setting the pe-*series-max properties, e.g.

> crm configure property pe-error-series-max=1000
>   pe-input-series-max=1000 pe-warn-series-max=1000

Answer (score 1):

/var/lib/pengine are files used by [pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org). There are probably lots of them, but I doubt theyre taking up much space. Pacemaker is a high-availability utility, so this means that box is probably a mission-critical box, and so I wouldnt mess around with it if you dont know what youre doing.

However Jansen is correct in that the extension of the file means nothing as to whether you can delete it.
The best idea if you want to delete files that you dont know if theyre needed is to move them to an alternate location. If the system continues to operate normally, you can delete them. If the system has issues, put them back.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and your ideas, but unfortunately I can't take any risk because is a production server but anyways, vendor came and solved just moving the logs to another file. Thank you again for your support as always.